# Find a formula for the sum of the $n$ terms of the sequence (Summations & Sequences)

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, summation

*Find a formula for the sum of the $n$ terms of the sequence*:

$1, 1 + 2, 1 + 2 + 2^{2}, 1 + 2 + 2^{2} + 2^{3}, ...$

My Approach:

When $n$ increases the sequence increases by $2^{n}$ for every $n$.

I believe the formula has a constant which is $1$ based on the sequence pattern.

When I sum up the sequence for every $n$ it is $1, 3, 7, 15, ...$

I believe it is an arithmetic progression where $a = 1$ and $a(n) = 2a(n-1) + 3$

Although the formula is not quite correct i got some of the correct answers but not all

for every $n$.

Any help or hints would be appreciated for this

Comment: (Note: I'm voting to close as *abstract* duplicate: the other question asks about finite sums as well.  This is the case $x=2$.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out anorton I can't believe I didnt see that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT: Partial sums of a geometric progression with parameters...